# Highcharts : Two marker symbol for the same point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I use HighCharts Version 3.0.9, I need to know if it is possible to set two marker symbol for the same point.

In my case I want to display an icon and the basic marker like this :

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And third option (first two are listed by @Mark) is to use separate series (scatter) with spcified marker and add points when you need another marker.

If you could use Highstock, then flag series would fit you the most, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

1.) Define a custom marker that is capable of drawing both shapes as in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/) example.

2.) Use the default marker and then use the [`Renderer`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) capablities of Highcharts to add the icon afterward.  Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bqjuk/) of this approach.